# combinar varios COUNT con JOIN

Tags: base-de-datos

Necesito calcular el numero de victimas, procesados y delitos, una vez que tenga contado esos datos necesito asociarlos para que todos me aparezcan en una sola consulta, tengo la tabla de `victmas`, `procesados` y `delitos` y todas ellas tienen en común una variable llamada `id_expedientes` , realicé este código, pero al momento de hacer la consulta me marca de `id_expedientes` es ambiguo

```
select Id_expediente,
       count(id_victima) as no_victima,
       count(id_procesado) as no_procesado,
       count(id_delito) as no_delito
from expedientes
left join procesados on procesados.id_expediente=expedientes.Id_expediente
left join victimas on victimas.id_expediente=expedientes.Id_expediente
left join delitos on delitos.Id_expediete=expedientes.Id_expediente
group by 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como `Id_expediente` es común a todas la tablas, cuando solo referencias la columna sin un alias o nombre de tabla, el motor no sabe o no puede decidir de que tabla será la columna, en tu caso solo habría que indicar alguna (cualquiera de las tablas)

```
select expedientes.Id_expediente,
       ...
```

De cualquier manera es recomendable que uses los alias de tablas que te permiten escribir un poco menos y evitan este tipo de problemas, por ejemplo:

```
select e.Id_expediente,
       count(v.id_victima) as no_victima,
       count(p.id_procesado) as no_procesado,
       count(d.id_delito) as no_delito
       from expedientes e
       left join procesados p
            on p.id_expediente=e.Id_expediente
       left join victimas v
            on v.id_expediente=e.Id_expediente
       left join delitos d
            on d.Id_expediente=e.Id_expediente
       group by e.Id_expediente;
```

Las letras `e`, `p`, `v`, `d`  las usamos como alias de cada tabla y en vez de utilizar el nombre completo de la tabla usamos este alias.

Comment: Se recomienda, por salud y por claridad del código, indicar siempre a qué tabla corresponde cada columna, **incluso aquellas que no tengan aparente riesgo de ambigüedad**. Tal es el caso de todas las columnas que estás usando con `COUNT`...  es decir: `count(v.id_victima) ... count(p.id_procesado)  ...  count(d.id_delito) ...`

Comment: @Patricio Moracho gracias por la ayuda, he coregido el codigo pero al momento de ejecutarlo me marca el erro   Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: @ErikaMellarkGonzalez, ese es otro problema distinto: la consulta seguramente esta demorando más del timeout de la conexión. Puede ser un problema de la consulta por falta de índices, o sencillamente demora mucho en cuyo caso deberías modificar el timeout. Saludos.